# minimizing the area between a circle and straight line

Tags: calculus

here is the problem (number 6)[image]

here is my (wrong) solution
first I see that the areas on both sides are symmetric and so the value of x for which the derivative is zero leads to the same for each half (if I minimize or maximize one half I do the same to the other)

the area of the region in the middle can be found by integrating the difference between the functions from 0 to any point x and I find that equal to $$\frac{\arccos\left(x\right)}{2}-\left(\frac{3x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}$$ 
 (here the top function is the circle and the bottom is the line)

the area of the region on the side can be found by integrating the difference again but from 1-x to 1 (here the top function is the line) and I find that equal to 
$$\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{\arccos\left(x\right)}{2}-\left(\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)$$

now I add both equations and differentiate , set it equal to zero an find the critical points of the function (I verified that this step is correct using desmos) then use the equation of the circle to find the intersection with the line and the answer I arrive at is 0.427 which is wrong..I double checked everything I did and still I can't find what exactly went wrong, my only guess is that something went wrong with the signs of the terms especially since in the first equation if you set $x=1$ this should lead to $\pi/4$ but I noticed it leads to $- \pi/4$ instead

Comment: Why don't you write down your solution, so that we can check it and comment on the problems, should there be any?

Comment: Suppose we told you that the number you gave in your question was wrong. Now what? You should show your work so that if you have a mistake, someone has a chance of identifying it instead of guessing where you might’ve gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the the line up by an infinitesimal amount d, each are on the side will increase by a region that we can approximate as a rectangle with height d and width equal to the distance from the vertical line to the circle. The area in the middle will decrease by a region that we can approximate by a rectangle that has height d and width equal to the width of the circle. So for the derivative to be zero, we need that the widths from the circle to vertical line add up to the width of the circle, which means that the width of the circle should be half the total width, which is 1.

If we draw a right triangle with one corner at the center of the circle, another one at an intersection between the line and the circle, and the third directly below the second point, then we have that the hypotenuse is 1, the width is .5 (because the width of the circle should be half the total width), and so the height is $\sqrt{1-.5^2}=\sqrt{.75}=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$, or about 0.866.